# Property project is missing in type `{}` but required in Readonly<Props>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import the `FirstTab` contents inside `Assets.tsx` just like shown in the working example in the StackBlitz editor code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-y7i3rr). In the editor example, `FirstTab` component is imported in `index.tsx`.

My `Assets.tsx` is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import JqxTabs from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxtabs";
import JqxGrid, {
  IGridProps,
  jqx
} from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxgrid";
;
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      FirstTab: any;
    }
  }
}

import FirstTab from "./FirstTab";

type Props = {
  project
};


export interface AssetsState extends IGridProps {
    project: {}
}


export class Assets extends React.PureComponent<Props, AssetsState> {
     private projectSpacesGridElement = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
     private myTabs = React.createRef<JqxTabs>();

constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        project: {}
     };
  }

  public render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <JqxTabs
        ref={this.myTabs}
        theme={"arctic"}
        width="1390px"
        initTabContent={this.initWidgets}
       >
        <ul>
          <li style={{ marginLeft: 30 }}>
            <div style={{ height: 20, marginTop: 5 }}>
              <div style={{ float: "left" }}></div>
              <div
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 4,
                  verticalAlign: "middle",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  float: "left"
                }}
              >
                Project Spaces
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div >
          <div id="jqxGrid" ref={this.projectSpacesGridElement} />
        </div>

      </JqxTabs>
  </div>

    );
  }

private initWidgets = (tab: any) => {
    switch (tab) {
      case 0:
        render(<FirstTab/>, this.projectSpacesGridElement.current!);
        break;

    }
  };

}
```

And my `FirstTab.tsx` is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import JqxGrid, {
  IGridProps,
  jqx
} from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxgrid";
import { properties } from "../properties";

type Props = {
    project
};

export interface PSState extends IGridProps {
       project: {}
    }

export default class FirstTab extends React.Component<Props, PSState> {

   private assetsDataGrid = React.createRef<JqxGrid>();
   private baseUrl = properties.baseUrlWs;


    constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         project: {},
    };

    }// End of Constructor

   render() {

    const source: any = {
      datafields: [
        { name: "id", type: "long" },
        { name: "assetsTypeId", type: "long" }
       ],
     deleterow: (rowid: number,commit:any): void => {
         commit(true);
      }, 
     datatype: "json",
      root: "company",
      url: this.baseUrl + `api/records/search/getNumbers`
    };
    return (
        <div>
         <JqxGrid
            ref={this.assetsDataGrid}
            width={"100%"}
            height={"100%"}
            theme={"arctic"}
           />        

          </div>

      );
    }
}//End of the Class
```

Here is the screenshot of the error that I'm getting on Line #81 in my Visual Studio code IDE.

[image]

**Text Based Description of above Error:**

On this line `render(<FirstTab/>, this.projectSpacesGridElement.current!);`, `<FirstTab/>` is throwing an error: Property `project` is missing in type `{}` but required in type `Readonly<Props>`.ts(2741)

Another thing I don't understand is why I'm getting this `render` related error as shown in the screenshot below. There is no error in the working example of StackBlitz editor that I shared above: 
[image]

**Text Based Description of above Error:**

On this line `render(<FirstTab/>, this.projectSpacesGridElement.current!);`,I'm seeing an error on `render` method which says `Cannot find`render`. Did you mean the instance member`this.render`? ts(2663)

Comment: Please try to avoid posting text as images. I'm at work and Imgur links are blocked, so I can't tell where your error is coming from.

Comment: @ChrisB. Please see the updated text based description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you defined type Props and said that your props need to have a project type within it.   I don't think you need any of that code and should probably just remove it.

```
type Props = {
  project
};
```

Typically when defining a custom prop type, you should give it a different name such as MyComponentPropType = { }.

Comment: Removing `type Props = {
  project
};` from `FirstTab` did remove the error. But that `render` related error is still there. Any idea what I'm doing wrong there? Thanks !

Comment: Changing it to `ReactDOM.render` solved the problem for `render` related error.

Comment: Actually I had to do this `import { render } from "react-dom";` to get rid of `render` related error. Using `ReactDOM.render`, I was still noticing console related errors. After doing an import, everything worked fine.

Comment: I just realized that I might need that type `Props`, what's the alternative to have that without generating any error? Thanks !